# Akka Quickstart: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, scala, reflection, akka

When running the official [Akka Quickstart](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/#running-the-example) on my Mac terminal, I get this error:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.8 ...
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator (file:/Users/helios/eclipse-workspace/akka-quickstart-java/sbt-dist/bin/sbt-launch.jar) to field java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ivy.util.url.IvyAuthenticator
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
reStart
```

Is this the intended result? How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a warning, not an error.

Here is a quote from Oracle JDK 9 Migration Guide

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7BB28E4D-99B3-4078-BDC4-FC24180CE82B

> **Understanding Runtime Access Warnings**
>
> Some tools and libraries use reflection to access parts of the JDK that are meant for internal use only. This illegal reflective access will be disabled in a future release of the JDK. In JDK 9, it is permitted by default and a warning is issued.
>
> For example, here is the warning issued when starting Jython:
>
> ```
> java -jar jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper (file:/C:/Jython/jython2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl.getFD()
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11)
> ```
>
> **If you see a warning like this, contact the maintainers of the tool or library.** The second line of the warning names the exact JAR file whose code used reflection to access an internal part of the JDK.
>
> By default, a maximum of one warning about reflective access is issued in the lifetime of the process started by the java launcher. The exact timing of the warning depends on the behavior of tools and libraries performing reflective–access operations. The warning may appear early in the lifetime of the process, or a long time after startup.
>
> You can disable the warning message on a library-by-library basis by using the `--add-opens` command line flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning, but followed with a NullPointerException that "this.text" is null...sorry I do not have the error now

I was on Java 11 and when I switched to Java 8 everything worked!